# Exporting One Value on Both Default and Named Exports (Circular)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, commonjs

I was recently working with a TypeScript project with `passport-aut0`. I installed the types for it with [the DefinitelyTyped `@types/passport-auth0` declaration file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/passport-auth0).

Importing the `Strategy` as a named import from `passport-auth0` worked well (I have `"esModuleInterop": true` in my tsconfig):

```js
import {Strategy} from 'passport-auth0';
```

But the `Strategy` is also exported as a default `export`. So, as in [the Readme](https://github.com/auth0/passport-auth0/blob/master/README.md), you should be able to import it like this:

```js
import Strategy from 'passport-auth0';
```

This did not work with `@types/passport-auth0`. The error message was like:

```
Type 'typeof import("/home/vsts/work/1/s/types/passport-auth0/index")' has no construct signatures.
```

I want to fix the type definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to fix this problem for others, and went down the rabbit hole of trying to export / import a value as both a default export and also a named export (with hints from [@nathan-shively-sanders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7851/nathan-shively-sanders)).

My solution (see https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/42315) ended up being the following.

The original type definitions looked something like this:

```js
//
// The class that will be exported / imported as both:
//
// - name export (works already because `export class`)
// - default export (doesn't work)
//
export class Strategy extends passport.Strategy { /* ... */ }

export interface Profile extends passport.Profile { /* ... */ }
export interface AuthenticateOptions extends passport.AuthenticateOptions { /* ... */ }
export interface StrategyOption { /* ... */ }
export interface StrategyOptionWithRequest extends StrategyOption { /* ... */ }
export interface ExtraVerificationParams { /* ... */ }
export type VerifyFunction = ( /* ... */ ) => void;
export type VerifyFunctionWithRequest = ( /* ... */ ) => void;
```

I had to:

1. **rename the class** from `Strategy` to `StrategyInternal` (so that I can export a circular reference without `Circular definition of import alias` when using `export import ...`)
2. **change the `export` before the class to `declare`**
3. **declare a namespace** with the new name `StrategyInternal` at the bottom of the file (this is called Namespace Merging)
4. **move all of the other interfaces and types to the namespace** and remove the `export`s
5. **update the references inside the class** from eg. `VerifyFunction` to `StrategyInternal.VerifyFunction`
6. **use `export import` inside the namespace** to export the value as a named export
7. **set the default export** with `export = StrategyInternal` at the bottom of the file

Here is the gist of my final solution:

```js
declare class StrategyInternal extends passport.Strategy {
    // Updated references to types and interfaces
    // Eg. changing `VerifyFunction` to `StrategyInternal.VerifyFunction`
}

declare namespace StrategyInternal {
    interface Profile extends passport.Profile { /* ... */ }
    interface AuthenticateOptions extends passport.AuthenticateOptions { /* ... */ }
    interface StrategyOption { /* ... */ }
    interface StrategyOptionWithRequest extends StrategyOption { /* ... */ }
    interface ExtraVerificationParams { /* ... */ }
    type VerifyFunction = ( /* ... */ ) => void;
    type VerifyFunctionWithRequest = ( /* ... */ ) => void;

    // NOTE: not true for `export import` statements
    // tslint:disable-next-line:strict-export-declare-modifiers
    export import Strategy = StrategyInternal;
}

export = StrategyInternal;
```

I just wanted to post this as the solution, since it seems to pass the tests and allows either of these styles of ESM imports (with `"esModuleInterop": true` in tsconfig):

```js
import {Strategy} from 'passport-auth0';
```

...or...

```js
import Strategy from 'passport-auth0';
```

---

In case you are not using ES Modules interop, these styles are also supported:

```js
import Strategy = require('passport-auth0');
```

...or...

```js
import {Strategy} = require('passport-auth0');
```

Or in CommonJS in JavaScript:

```js
const Strategy = require('passport-auth0');
```

...or...

```js
const {Strategy} = require('passport-auth0');
```